# Setup for logging/displaying what command an OBD scan tool sends

Tags: arduino, can, fault, obd

I came across this video: youtube.com/watch?v=VtMvccqE8ks

Any idea/resources how to build this setup? I am not much interested in monitoring the CAN bus for commands (headers or CAN IDs) of power window, AC temperature, fan speed etc., but more interested in seeing what command does a scan tool send if it has to check for DTCs (trouble codes) for ABS or BCM or battery control module. (Currently I get P and U codes from mode $03)

I have tried monitoring CAN bus and have been quite successful in pulling out CAN IDs for AC fan speed, AC temperature, Power windows, parking brakes, gear in which the car is etc., but monitoring CAN bus never gave me DTCs of ABS, BCM, Airbags etc. So, reverse engineering a scan tool feels like a plausible solution where I can log what requests the scan tool is sending.

Comment: Monitoring the CAN bus is monitoring the CAN bus. If you can log the current activity then you should be able to log the activity generated by the tool. Take the log and filter out the normal packets and you'll be left with the ones generated by the tool.

Comment: This information is all in the standards. If you're doing it professionally it might be worth subscribing. http://www.sae.org/

Comment: @Andrew If I plug the scan tool to the OBD port of the car, how do I monitor the CAN bus? What kind of setup do I need?
Currently, I use  http://www.obdlink.com/sxusb/ this USB OBD tool to connect the OBD end of the tool to the OBD port of the car and the USB end of the tool to the USB port of my laptop. Then I send ATMA command (through PuTTY) and see the CAN bus data. If I connect the scan tool to the OBD port of the car how do I see/log what command is the scan tool sending?

Comment: @SoumyaSen By connecting them both to the CAN bus at the same time. You can connect multiple devices to a CAN bus, that's the whole point of using it. How you physically do that is up to you, it is simply an exercise in connecting wires from pin 1 to pin 1, pin 2 to pin 2 etc... Either find and purchase an OBD splitter or get a soldering iron out, either would work. You should only need the CAN and possibly power and ground pins rather than all of the OBD pins but it depends what your equipment expects in order to work.

Comment: @Andrew I am thinking a 'Y' shaped junction box kind of thing, one end connects to the OBD port, other end to my laptop and 3rd end to a professional scan tool. So I am constantly monitoring the 
CAN bus and any command I send via the scan tool is captured in the CAN bus log. 

Do you have any good resources to build this that you can recommend me? Any particular software you feel works the best for logging CAN data?

Answer (score 1):

The CAN bus is a lovely open standard, easy to monitor and easy to put whatever you want on it. This is why cars are so easy to hack; everything on the CAN bus is accessible from everything else on the CAN bus. This gives you the simple option of plugging into the bus and read.

Plug in a scan tool bought from some online supplier for about £10-£20 ($15-$30) and monitor the line as you were doing before, reading the signals from the scan tool.

Comment: If I plug the scan tool to the OBD port of the car, how do I monitor the CAN bus? What kind of setup do I need?
Currently, I use  http://www.obdlink.com/sxusb/ this USB OBD tool to connect the OBD end of the tool to the OBD port of the car and the USB end of the tool to the USB port of my laptop. Then I send ATMA command (through PuTTY) and see the CAN bus data. If I connect the scan tool to the OBD port of the car (as you said) how do I see/log what command is the scan tool sending?

Comment: Connect an oscilloscope or similar to the wires of the CAN bus. How were you monitoring it before? Would have thought that a set of flying leads would do the job quite well.

Comment: https://theksmith.com/software/hack-vehicle-bus-cheap-easy-part-1/
https://theksmith.com/software/hack-vehicle-bus-cheap-easy-part-2/
Step 3 of the link - Connect USB OBD tool (one end to the car OBD, other end to the laptop, send ATMA command and see the data coming in. Then use excel to find the headers and then finding manually which header corresponds to what function in the car.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that DTCs are not proactively broadcast by the ECUs, but are only returned in response to a specific request.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs should have everything to get you started, esp. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#CAN_.2811-bit.29_bus_format.

Comment: Yes, I do get P and U codes from mode $03, but now I want to turn my attention towards other DTCs like ABS, BCM and from other control modules. Since DTCs are not proactively broadcast by the ECUs, but are only returned in response to a specific request, I am planning to reverse engineer a scan tool to log the requests sent by the scan tool for ABS, BCM, Airbag etc.
Hence, I want to know what setup should I do to log the requests from a scan tool